# Как правильно обфусцировать код используя ProGuard?

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard

Решил сделать обфускацию кода своего Android проекта. В интеренете прочитал что от хакеров можно защитить приложение используя ProGuard или DexGuard. Как правильно нужно настроить проект чтобы заработал ProGuard (я использую Gradle)? Как потом убедиться что он работает и что он поменял имена классов и методов? Может есть какие нибудь другие обфускаторы которые справляются с задачей лучше чем ProGuard? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Декомпилируйте - меняете весь код на полученный - компилируете

Comment: чтобы включить, достаточно указать `minifyEnabled true` в конфиге грэдла. Эта строка - достаточное основание верить, что код обфусцирован. Все необходимое изложено [в офф. доках](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Gradle --> build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true //обфускация
        shrinkResources true //удаление мусора
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Для надежности можете перевести программу на модульный режим/подгружать dex, который у вас будет полность обфусцирован и уже в самой программе, перед прогрузом, будет проводиться деобфускация